# RevMob cache ad to display when there is no internet connection

Tags: ios, xcode, caching, ads, revmob

Can we cache the ad and display it when there is no internet connection?

I have read the sdk specs and it seems that it doesn't say anything regarding the offline mode...

These is what I've read :
http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html

Also if somehow caching is possible, will it generate income?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can cache the ad and display it whenever you want, but if there is no internet connection, RevMob's servers won't be notified and it will not generate income.